# Web Scraping for automation

Tags: javascript, web-scraping

Need to scrape the data(prices of hotels for specific date) of all the hotels on websites like booking.com, expedia.com, cleartrip.com and Agoda.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Firstly, no need for #HashTags here. this is not really a "Give me a code for this" site. Its more of a "Help me find why my code is not working". There will be time where people do create answers for people who are asking for full script development, so try and get something working and then post it on here. Enoy your time here.

Comment: Any chance to see what you have tried so far? it would be great to see what you have already tried so that we can help you to improve (or help resolving issues) your code.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of what i have tried till now - 
Aim - To scrape hotel names along with the prices

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import BeautifulSoup


#city = str(raw_input())

#now = time.time()
#then = now + 24*3600
#tommorow = time.strftime("%d %m %Y",time.localtime(then)).replace(" ","%2F")
#today = time.strftime("%d %m %Y",time.localtime(now)).replace(" ","%2F")


#url = "http://www.cleartrip.com/hotels/results?city="+city+"&chk_in="+today+"&chk_out="+tommorow+"&adults1=1&children1=0&num_rooms=1"

url = "http://www.cleartrip.com/hotels/results?city=Gurgaon&state=&country=&area=&poi=&hotelName=&dest_code=&chk_in=28%2F02%2F2015&chk_out=01%2F03%2F2015&adults1=1&children1=0&num_rooms=1"
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(url)


content = browser.page_source

#print content

browser.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

hotelNames = soup.find_all('a',class_="hotelDetails")
roomRents   = soup.find_all('span',class_="INR")
hotelRatings     = soup.find_all('li',class_="review")



names  =  [name.get('title') for name in hotelNames]
rents   =  [span.get("data-pr") for span in roomRents]
ratingss = [rating.find_all("span")[1].get("title") for rating in hotelRatings]

print names
print rents
print reviews
```